# CS0246: The type or namespace name 'itextsharp' could not be found

Tags: itext

Hello:  I received the above error message and searched for a solution from various websites.  I have copied the itextsharp.dll library into the bin folder of my C# project, into the c:\windows\assembly folder, c:\Program Files\Microsoft.Net\Primary Interop Assemblies folder, and the c:\windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\2.0.50727 folder.  Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error.  Can anyone help me with this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add it as a reference to your project in Visual Studio also?

Comment: Yes, I did add it as a reference in Visual Studio.  It does not appear in the web.config file as does the System.DirectoryServices reference does.

Answer (score 2):

Download the  (itextsharp.dll) file and paste that file in your drive.

And then open you visualstudio right click on the solution explorer. Click on Add Reference

select the browse option and and click on the file  where it is stored.It will automatically appear in your bin folder.